# How to override FOSUserBundle's EmailConfirmationListener

Tags: events, symfony, fosuserbundle, event-listener

I activated user confirmation for FOSUserBundle. But I don't want to take the response from the original listener

```
$url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
```

I want to chose another route. I tried to extend the EventListener

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener as BaseListener;
// ...

class EmailConfirmationListener extends BaseListener
{
    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {    
        $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, EventListeners don't seem to be extendable, just as Controllers or Forms are. (Just in case you wonder: of course my bundle is a child of the FOSUserBundle.)

So I want to avoid editing those two lines directly in the vendor folder (as it would be very bad practice to do so!). So what are my ways out of this calamity?

Comment: I already had an idea: Changing the controller and action in my routes definition. But I don't like this idea as it is against my understanding of readable, maintainable and self-explanatory code.

Comment: Ugh, looking at the `FOSUserBundle` sources I can tell a PR is needed to make it possible to configure which class is used for the `fos_user.listener.email_confirmation` service. Now it's [hardcoded](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/email_confirmation.xml#L8). If it wasn't, you could extend the class and override a parameter to make the bundle use your subclass instead.

Comment: What's a PR? Can I override the service definition XML file? That'd be slack...

Comment: A pull request for the bundle with code changes that fix that problem.

Comment: What is hardcoded here? you can just override the service `fos_user.listener.email_confirmation` with your own class and FOSUserBundle will use it ... A parameter would have been a better choice but the service definition can easily be overriden.

Comment: While a PR introducing a parameter for the class would maybe be nice ... you probably miss the fact that not all those injected services needed in the original listener will be necessary for a custom one - for example `@session`. That's probably why one has chosen not to introduce another parameter to change the class only i guess ... as it's still easy to override the service completely and inject some different services needed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just override the service `fos_user.listener.email_confirmation` by creating a service with the same name in your `config.yml` ...

```
# app/config/config.yml

services:
    fos_user.listener.email_confirmation:
        class:        "Acme\MyBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener"
        arguments:    ["@fos_user.mailer", "@fos_user.util.token_generator", "@router", "@session"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

... or even cleaner - create a parameter that's being used by your service:

```
parameters:
    my.funky_parameter.class: "Acme\MyBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener"

services:
    fos_user.listener.email_confirmation:
        class: "%my.funky_parameter.class%"
        # ...
```

... or inside your bundle's xml/yml/php configuration file loaded by the bundle's extension. Make sure your bundle is being registered after FOSUserBundle in `AppKernel.php` when choosing this way.

... or the best method:

change the original service's class name in a compiler pass as the documentation chapter [**How to Override any Part of a Bundle**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration) suggests.

Maybe take a dive into the chapter [How to work with Compiler Passes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) before choosing this option.

Comment: Thanks! Never really bothered with compiler passes before. Super useful though, will definitely be using this technique more often in future :)

Comment: Thank you. Compiler pass method is the right way to do this kind of stuff.