# FOSUserBundle - Force password change after first login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

In a Symfony2 application using FOSUserBundle for user management, the user table has been filled through an import script from a csv file and the password generated from a combination of data.

I would like to force the user to change his password at the first login.

When the event `FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN` occurs, redirect to the route `fos_user_change_password` if the field `last_login` is NULL.

My idea was rewriting the method `onImplicitLogin(UserEvent $event)` of the class `AGI\UserBundle\EventListener\LastLoginListener` like this but the class is not overwritten:

```
public function onImplicitLogin(UserEvent $event) {
    $user = $event->getUser ();

    if ($user->getLastLogin () === null) {
        $user->setLastLogin ( new \DateTime () );
        $this->userManager->updateUser ( $user );
        $response = new RedirectResponse ( $this->router->generate ( 'fos_user_change_password' ) );
        $this->session->getFlashBag ()->add ( 'notice', 'Please change your password' );
        $event->setResponse ( $response );
    }
}
```

I already have a bundle overwriting FOSUserBundle and it works for controllers, forms, etc but It looks like it is not the way to do it with eventListeners.

How can I force the user to change the password after the first login?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why the listener doesn't work. I don't know what you mean by "but the class is not overwritten."

Comment: @sjagr I'm facing the same problem as explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745087/how-to-override-fosuserbundles-emailconfirmationlistener) but I can not report the solution to my problem because I don't find the service to overwrite.

Comment: Are you looking for `fos_user.security.implicit_login`?

Answer (score 9):

With the help of the precious hint from @sjagr about `fos_user.security.implicit_login` that drove me to `fos_user.security.implicit_login` and an external topic about [doing stuff right after login](http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/), I got a working solution.

AGI\UserBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

```
login_listener:
    class: 'AGI\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener'
    arguments: ['@security.context', '@router', '@event_dispatcher']
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login', method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

AGI\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener.php

```
<?php

namespace AGI\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

class LoginListener {

    private $securityContext;
    private $router;
    private $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Router $router, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher) {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted ( 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' )) {
            $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken ()->getUser ();

            if ($user->getLastLogin () === null) {
                $this->dispatcher->addListener ( KernelEvents::RESPONSE, array (
                        $this,
                        'onKernelResponse' 
                ) );
            }
        }
    }
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
        $response = new RedirectResponse ( $this->router->generate ( 'fos_user_change_password' ) );
        $event->setResponse ( $response );
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You should remove "@doctrine" from the arguments in your service since you're not declaring it in your construct.

Comment: This solution forces the user to the "change password" page immediately after login, but what if the user just ignores the change and navigates to another page?

Comment: Now you probably want to use AuthorizationChecker instead of SecurityContext.

Answer (score 1):

If you require user change password due to some business rules, you can use kernel request EventListener:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class ChangePasswordListener
{
    private TokenStorageInterface $security;

    private RouterInterface $router;

    private array $excludedRoutes = [
        'admin_change_password',
        'admin_login',
        'admin_login_check',
        'admin_logout',
    ];

    public function __construct(
        TokenStorageInterface $security,
        RouterInterface $router
    ) {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        if (false === $event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $currentRoute = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
        if (\in_array($currentRoute, $this->excludedRoutes, true)) {
            return;
        }

        $token = $this->security->getToken();

        if (null === $token) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();

        if ($user instanceof UserInterface && $user->shouldPasswordChange()) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin_security_profile_change_password'));
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

services.yaml:

```
services:
    App\EventListener\ChangePasswordListener:
        arguments:
            - '@security.token_storage'
            - '@router'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: -100 }
```

You should provide also own UserInterface with method "shouldPasswordChange" and custom implementation of it.

It works great with Symfony 5.0 and PHP 7.4 but if you modify this code it should works also for lower PHP versions.