# Disable automatic login after registration in Symfony's FOSUserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Using latest Symfony and FOSUserbundle, after successfully registering a new user, the user is automatically logged in. I want to prevent this. My reason is that only a special user should be able to register new users.

I guess I have to override the registerAction in the RegisterController of the bundle, but I don't know how.

I tried: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html, but it seems to be outdated, no user is created with this method.

Any hints are appreciated.

**Edit:**

I found out that I did not create the child bundle correctly. I also had to create my own EventListener. It works now when I overwrite the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` event.

Strange thing is that when I use the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED`event, both events are dispatched, my bundle's and the  FOSUserbundle's, so that the user is redirected to the correct site, but logged in as the new user.

***Edit 2:***

So this is in my listener:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationCompleted',
    );
}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent  $event)
{
    $url = $this->router->generate('admin');

    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}

public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent  $event)
{

}
```

I set the redirection in the `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS`event and the `REGISTRATION_COMPLETED`is empty. With the debugger I can verify that my own listener's event is called, but the original event is also called.

Comment: docs look ok to me.  There are a number of ways of overriding a bundles file.  Are you making a 'child' of the userbundle as in the docs? or something different?  Also, if you are after an admin to only be able to create users, maybe the register side of FOSuserBundle is the wrong bit? Surely creating a CRUD to manage users behind an admin firewall would be better?

Comment: @DevDonkey: You were right, I failed to create the bundle correctly. Seems to work now. Maybe creating a CRUD would have been easier.

Comment: cool, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no need to do any of these. The `fos_user.listener.authentication` service is removed from the container if `use_authentication_listener` is set to false.

See [line 74-76](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/5850fba5f65b16ddb293f6635bbb8ac4aa293883/DependencyInjection/FOSUserExtension.php#L77) in `FOS\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\FOSUserExtension`.

This information is also included in document [FOS UserBundle Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with a Listener, In fos user bundle, it authenticates user with  after registration.

file :`friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/EventListener/AuthenticationListener.php`

class : `FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener`

If you check this class you would see it tracks `REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` Event.

In `Authenticatiton Listener` It dispatches Event after triggering `logInUser` function. Therefore you have to logout user in your listener which subscribes `REGISTRATION COMPLETED.

you can check https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.rst for writing your listener to logout user.

Note : It may not be a good way log-in log-out user in every registration process, but if you use fosuserbundle easiest way and minimum footprint would be this, if there is already a yml configuration doesn't exists, actually in code there is no direction of yml conf. So this approach would be min. footprint.

```
    try {
        $this->loginManager->logInUser($this->firewallName, $event->getUser(), $event->getResponse());

        $eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN, new UserEvent($event->getUser(), $event->getRequest()));
    } catch (AccountStatusException $ex) {
        // We simply do not authenticate users which do not pass the user
        // checker (not enabled, expired, etc.).
    }
```

Comment: I don't want the user to be logged in in the first place. That's why I overwrite the `REGISTRATION_COMPLETED`event where the new user is authenticated by default.

Comment: Do you mean you extended the bundle when you say override the event ?

Comment: Ooops I just get learned the technique to override a service/listener by service.yml thats cool stuff :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745087/how-to-override-fosuserbundles-emailconfirmationlistener

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This technique works on Symfony 3.3, I'm unaware if this works on lower versions.

The correct way of doing this is by creating a [Compiler Pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

You can also: Override the service by adding a new service using the same name: fos_user.listener.authentication on your app/config.yml file or on your bundle config file and adding your new class to it as I've done below and add this

Here is how to override the automatic logging when registering a new user using the compiler pass technique.

**The Compiler Pass**

```
namespace arpa3\UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use arpa3\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;


class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface {

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('fos_user.listener.authentication');
        $definition->setClass(AuthenticationListener::class);
    }

}
```

**The Service Override**

```
namespace arpa3\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Security\LoginManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;

class AuthenticationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var LoginManagerInterface
     */
    private $loginManager;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firewallName;

    /**
     * AuthenticationListener constructor.
     *
     * @param LoginManagerInterface $loginManager
     * @param string                $firewallName
     */
    public function __construct(LoginManagerInterface $loginManager, $firewallName)
    {
        $this->loginManager = $loginManager;
        $this->firewallName = $firewallName;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
           // You can disable any of them or all of them as you want
           //FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'authenticate',
           //FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'authenticate',
           //FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED => 'authenticate',
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param FilterUserResponseEvent  $event
     * @param string                   $eventName
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher
     */
    public function authenticate(FilterUserResponseEvent $event, $eventName, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        try {
            $this->loginManager->logInUser($this->firewallName, $event->getUser(), $event->getResponse());

            $eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN, new UserEvent($event->getUser(), $event->getRequest()));
        } catch (AccountStatusException $ex) {
            // We simply do not authenticate users which do not pass the user
            // checker (not enabled, expired, etc.).
        }
    }
}
```

**Register your Compiler Pass on your main bundle file**

```
    namespace arpa3\UserBundle;

use arpa3\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class arpa3UserBundle extends Bundle {

    public function getParent () {

        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }

    /**
     *
     * This injects a Compiler Pass that is used to override the automatic login after registration of a new user
     * We have done this in order to disable the "by default" behaviour given that only admins can register users
     * and logging in into the newly created account automatically is just not a desired behaviour
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function build ( ContainerBuilder $container ) {

        parent ::build( $container );

        $container -> addCompilerPass( new OverrideServiceCompilerPass() );

    }

}
```

There are other ways such as overriding the authentication service on your config.yml but the solution above is the cleanest and most maintainable solution I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, as you said your listeners are called but the order is not correct, so you need to make your listener be executed before the default one
In order to do that change

> FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS =>
>   'onRegistrationSuccess'

to

> FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS =>
>   ['onRegistrationSuccess',-10],

Notice the **-10** there, this changes the priority of the listener.

```
class RegistrationSuccessEventListener implements EventSubscriberInterface{


private $router;

public  function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router){

        $this->router = $router;

}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    //this will be called before

    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => ['onUserRegistrationSuccess', -30],
    );

}

/**
 * @param FormEvent $event
 * When the user registration is completed redirect
 * to the employee list page and avoid the automatic
 * mail sending and user authentication that happends
 *
 */
public  function  onUserRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event){



    $url = $this->router->generate('employees_list');

    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));

}




}
```

I am using symfony 2.8 with the FOSBundle version

> friendsofsymfony/user-bundle           dev-master 1f97ccf Symfony FOSUserBundle

according to the output of `composer info`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I cannot test it now as the project has already been finished.